# dax - pivot - different granulities

Tags: excel, pivot, dax, powerpivot

together

I am currently faced with the challenge of somehow connecting different granulities in the data model (Powerpivot).

I get my sales figures at the product level as follows:

```
ID - Date - Value - State 

ID: 123A
Date: 01.01.2019
Value: 5000
State: 10
```

My table with the annual goals is structured as follows:

```
Area - Category - Month - Goal

Area: A
Category: A1
Month: 01.01.2019
Goal: 1.000.000
```

The product is assigned to the category.

So:

```
Category - ID
A1       - 123A
A1       - 124A
A2       - 125A
....
```

How can I connect these tables "Professional" so that I can display them in my Pivot table as follows

```
Area - Category - Sales - Goal
```

Best Regards
Joshua

Comment: Where does `Sales` come from? `Value`?

Comment: Yes, that is the raw sales table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want a data model similar to this where `Dates` is your calendar table:

[image: Data Model]

Where the relationships are

```
Categories[ID] --> Sales[ID]
Categories[Category] --> Goals[Category]
Dates[Date] --> Sales[Date]
Dates[Month] --> Goals[Month]
```

---

Note that the right-hand side has many-to-many relationships. These are equivalent to having a unique column bridge table in between.

```
Categories[Category] * <-- 1 CategoryBridge[Category] 1 --> * Goals[Category]
Dates[Month] * <-- 1 MonthBridge[Month] 1 --> * Goals[Month]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Alexis, thanks for your reply! Where is the unique column for month? How can I link the tbl Goals und Dates when both have no unique month column? The same for Categories[Category] -> Goals[Category]

Comment: If you can't create a many-to-many relationship, go with bridge tables as in my edit.

Comment: Is there any chance that you show me your approach in the file I provided? Unfortunately it is not working. I have created unique columns/ tables work category and month but the pivot table does not include this relationship

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MTFHN2_Bi8h1vSZeWgmIaS4eaaPSh-lK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey Alexis, thanks for your awesome approach! Could you please include the pivot table in your file? I still have no relation between the tables if I want to know how many sales I had in one category against the goal for a specific month

Comment: That's because your `Goals[Category]` and `Goals[Area]` columns don't match the corresponding ones in the `Categories` table. You need to fix that. I don't know how you intended them to work.

Comment: Hey Alexis, thanks for the reply. Area is just a parent category. The connection of area to category is exemplified in the file. What exactly do you mean by "fixed"?

Comment: The connection on `Category` has no matches because one table has text values like `A1`, `A2` and the other has numeric values like `1`, `2`.

Comment: Hey Alexis, you are right. There was a mistake. I have fixed that with a simple unique relation but the result was the same. I can`t link the sales and the goals in one pivot table on area and category level and a monthly view. Could you help in any way?

Comment: You'll need to use the columns from the bridge tables in your pivot table rather than `Categories` or `Dates` in order for the filtering to propagate as expected.